# What is the difference between "short int" and "int" in C?

Tags: c, types

How is short int (or short) and int different in C? They have the same size and range. If they are essentially the same, what is the use of having two data types?

Comment: In 16-bit compilers, they have the same size and range. Practically all modern compilers for mainstream platforms have `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They **may** have the same size, but it is guaranteed that `int` is equal to or bigger than `short int`.

Comment: What's actually guaranteed is that the *ranges* of `short int` are at least -32767 .. +32767, and the range of `short int` is a subset of the range of `int`. It follows from this that `short int` and `int` are both at least 16 bits. Due to padding bits, it's theoretically possible to have `sizeof (short int) > sizeof (int)`, but it's very unlikely.

Comment: @KeithThompson can you elaborate regarding `sizeof (short int) > sizeof (int)` ?

Comment: @icepack: Integer types can have padding bits, bits that don't contribute to the value. For example, a conforming implementation could *in theory* have `short` with 32 bits (16 of them padding bits) and `int` with 24 bits (all significant). I can't think of any reason to do such a silly thing, but the standard doesn't forbid it.

Answer (score 33):

In theory/by the C standard, they could be of any size as long as `16 bit <= short <= int`.

In the real world, this is how the sizes are implemented.

```
CPU             short   int
8 bit           16      16
16 bit          16      16
32 bit          16      32
64 bit          16      32
```

Comment: Have you checked it in ansi c in linux in 64 bit and visual studio in window in 64 bit I just want to know..

Comment: @BharatSharma 64 bit only makes a difference to the sizes of `long` and `long long`. Apparently some 64-bit systems define long as 64 bits, while other systems implement the C99/C11 standard and use `long long` for 64 bits, leaving `long` as 32 bits.

Comment: thanks actually once i found issue related to long so I was thinking that may also be possible to short... :)

Comment: They can't be *any* size; both must be at least 16 bits. BTW, I've worked on systems with 32-bit (Cray T3E) and 64-bit (Cray T90) `short`.

Comment: @Lundin So is this true that in 64bit arch, `int` is same with `long` (both are 32bit)?

Comment: Just realized that this has the interesting implication that on platforms where `short==int`, `USHRT_MAX` must be a negative `int`, most probably `-1` for two's complement platforms. :) (Interestingly, glibc makes `USHRT_MAX` on such platforms unsigned but it shouldn't be, because `int` is what you get by promoting `unsigned int`.)

Answer (score 6):

Never rely on a datatype being a given size in C. Always check the bounds in limits.h if in doubt.

Comment: Except, of course, if you're using `uint32_t` and friends from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: That is part of the C99 standard which brings us back to the question raised by others re what OS/compiler is being used.

Answer (score 3):

Actually everything depends on compiler and system both. But the basic rule says that int can never be less than short and can never be greater than long.

short <= int <= long

Comment: char <= short <= int <= long <= long long. Note that long long is not supported in [ISO C90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system. Some OSes won't have the same length for both types.

Answer (score 1):

**[C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)**

All that we now for sure is that:

```
2 <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)
```

*5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`* gives the minimum sizes:

> 1 [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown [...]
>
> - UCHAR_MAX 255 // 2 8 − 1
> - USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - UINT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2 32 − 1
> - ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2 64 − 1

*6.2.5 Types* then says:

> 8 For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
> (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
> subrange of the values of the other type.

and *6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers* determines the relative conversion ranks:

> 1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which
>   shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short
>   int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>   signed integer type, if any.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has
>   greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same today. My conclusion is it depends on the word length of the machine architecture on which your program is getting executed.
As per C99 limits.h documentation.

```
/* Minimum and maximum values a `signed short int' can hold.  */
#  define SHRT_MIN  (-32768)
#  define SHRT_MAX  32767

/* Maximum value an `unsigned short int' can hold.  (Minimum is 0.)  */
#  define USHRT_MAX 65535

/* Minimum and maximum values a `signed int' can hold.  */
#  define INT_MIN   (-INT_MAX - 1)
#  define INT_MAX   2147483647

/* Maximum value an `unsigned int' can hold.  (Minimum is 0.)  */
#  define UINT_MAX  4294967295U

/* Minimum and maximum values a `signed long int' can hold.  */
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64
#   define LONG_MAX 9223372036854775807L
#  else
#   define LONG_MAX 2147483647L
#  endif
#  define LONG_MIN  (-LONG_MAX - 1L)

/* Maximum value an `unsigned long int' can hold.  (Minimum is 0.)  */
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64
#   define ULONG_MAX    18446744073709551615UL
#  else
#   define ULONG_MAX    4294967295UL
#  endif
```

Let me know if anyone has better answer.

Comment: just to add try this

Comment: short int i = 2147483647;
 printf("%d %d %d\n",i, i+1,i+10);

Comment: int i = 2147483647;
 printf("%d %d %d\n",i, i+1,i+10);

Comment: i was working on a 64 bit machine and it is good observation for testing people to observe the rollover issues

Answer (score 0):

> "A short integer in one programming language may be a different size
>   in a different language or on a different processor. In some languages
>   this size is fixed across platforms, while in others it is
>   machine-dependent. In some languages this datatype does not exist at
>   all."

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Short_integer)

Comment: But the question is about C.

Comment: Yup and the source link posted shows the difference for C, C++, C# and Java.

Comment: The portion you quoted doesn't answer the question. (BTW, that paragraph was later deleted from the article.)

Answer (score 0):

short and int must be at least 16 bits, long must be at least 32 bits, and that short is no longer than int, which is no longer than long. Typically, short is 16 bits, long is 32 bits, and int is either 16 or 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler.
In some compilers int is 2 bytes and in other compilers is 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution - but what does this answer offer that isn't already stated in the other 11 answers?